# Where Can I get the jelly bean notification panel source code

Tags: android

I am a new android programmer , I have looked around the internet for jelly bean notification panel source code but couldn't get success yet , I want to use a sliding panel just like jelly bean notification panel which slides from top to bottom.
Please help me to get the source code.

Comment: will you please elobrate, your effort in question

Comment: If you're developing an app, look for SlidingDrawer widget http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar

It's hosted on Github and also on Google's own servers.